# Error TF31002 when connecting TFS 2015 XAML build agent to Azure DevOps Server 2019

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

During the upgrade we changed from http to https.  I cannot get this to connect with the new https URL, I get error tf31002: Unable to connect.  One odd thing is I can connect Visual Studio 2015 on this machine to the new URL with no issues.  I am using TFS 2015.4.2.  I know I need to get rid of XAML builds, but these are the last of them.  Out of over 1000 builds we have these 10 or so XAML builds left.

Comment: Do you mean you upgrade your TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps Server 2019, and [set up HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/setup-secure-sockets-layer?view=azure-devops) for the Azure DevOps Server 2019? And do you mean you want to config TFS 2015 Build Service to connect to Azure DevOps Server 2019?

Comment: Please provide more details about how you connect TFS 2015 XAML build agent to Azure DevOps Server 2019, screenshots would be better. In addition, we encourage you to [migrate your XAML builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/migrate-from-xaml-builds?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 0):

If you set up HTTPS for your on-premise server, you need to follow the following link to install the Certificate and update Build Configurations:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/setup-secure-sockets-layer?view=azure-devops#installing-certificats-build-svrs

We encourage you to migrate your XAML builds:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/migrate-from-xaml-builds?view=azure-devops